# What Causes the Changes in Singer Voices Like Mick Jagger's?

Tags: voice, voice-change

His voice has gone from fairly musical/tonal to being more shouted than anything else. This was at least somewhat inspired by a recent question about the effects of smoking on a voice over time. Is it smoking and drinking, vocal abuse/overuse or other forms of injury that can happen over decades?

I will understand if this question is too speculative in nature and needs to be closed but couldn't think of a better way to phrase it or better place to ask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it smoking and drinking, vocal abuse/overuse or other forms of injury that can happen over decades?

In part, yes, but it's also just age.  Epithelial and connective tissue loses elasticity.  Cartilage becomes stiffer as it ossifies.  Muscles may lose their strength for any of several reasons.  All of these tissues are present in the larynx, and the changes affect the way it vibrates and the ability of the singer to control its vibration.  No singer sounds at 79 like a 29-year old, no matter what sort of injury filled or injury free life the voice may have been subjected to.

Comment: Yeah, though [Ella at 67](https://youtu.be/qqz9FyIFjxU) is still quite something!

Comment: @AndyBonner indeed, though she was 62 in 1979.

Comment: I was well impressed with McCartney at Glastonbury this year. 80 years old & everything still in its original key. Darned impressive.

Comment: Cher is doing well too. Seems like the women fare better than the men in general though there are exceptions.

Comment: Oh… McCartney smokes. That puts paid to a lot of the recent discussions then ;) https://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-10671301/Windswept-Sir-Paul-McCartney-79-puffs-cigarette-relaxes-St-Barts-break.html

Comment: The extended time spent abusing ciggies, alchohol and drugs probably also has something to do with it. Paul is a vegetarian which probably indicates an at least somewhat healthy lifestyle.

Comment: @NeilMeyer - but now you're in danger of heading off in entire dietary regimen structures…

Comment: Lifestyle is important for singers. You are not going to sing well if your cardiovascular system is not healthy.

Comment: @NeilMeyer - you're caught in the rabbit hole. This is a 'millennial/first world issue', something no-one ever thought about in the slightest until relatively recently. Pavarotti smoked & was overweight… I'm not saying it's not going to kill you sooner, *on average*, I'm saying it's a recent 'worry', which is now in danger of looking up its own a** in the hands on ill-informed people following idiotic regimes in the mistaken belief it's 'good for you'. Trappers in the US North West C18 thought rabbit was good for them - they ate shedloads of it… & died in their droves of malnutrition.